# Job Control in CUPS printing

Tags: printing, cups-lpd, job-control

I've recently moved my laptop from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm tryinig to configure my work's network printer.

I'm configuring it by configuring CUPS in Ubuntu. Every time I try to print anything, it prints an error page saying "Error: PostScript printing not licensed for this printer."

Before, when I tried to print in Windows I had to put a job control account number that I had configured in the printer settings. Now, in Ubuntu, I'm not able to find where should I write it. I think this may cause the error because it is also shown in Windows when someone tries to print without using the code.

I've tried to configure the printer with the URL: socket://account_code@IP:port with no good results.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

J

Comment: What is the printer?

Comment: The printer is Sharp MX-M202D. Thanks!